# Vaadin Grid change Multiselection limit

Tags: java, grid, vaadin, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin 8 and i'm using a grid with multiselection enabled but i can only select 3 rows as much.

I've enabled Multiselection with

```
protected Grid<java.lang.String> canalesTV;
canalesTV.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTI);
```

I can't find any method which let me change how many rows can be selected.

Does anyone know how to change this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know there's no such limit. Please provide more details about your scenario, for example, how do you know it allows only 3? What's happening, are you getting an error somewhere? It's not visually updating the selection? etc...

Comment: Ok, i discovered that the problem was that i had was that i had a row repeated several times and it only selected the first one,so there wasn't limit after all. How can I mark this issue as closed?

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, and after a few days you can accept it as the correct one :)